# Arrange integers 1 to 1000 so that the average of any pair is not located between the two numbers

Tags: combinatorics

This is question 36 from '102 Combinatorial Problems from the training of the USA IMO team'. The question is

> Determine, with proof, if it is possible to arrange 1, 2, ..., 1000 in
> a row such that the average of any pair of distinct numbers is not
> located in between the two numbers.

My solution is different from the official one, and I want to get peoples' opinion on whether it's valid. My solution is:

Consider an arrangement of the integers between 1 and 1000 inclusive:

$$\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{1000} \} $$

For $x_2$ to not be in between any two numbers that average to $x_2$, we must have

$$x_2 \neq (x_1 + x_3) / 2, \\
 x_2 \neq (x_1 + x_4) / 2  \\
... \\
x_2 \neq (x_1 + x_{1000}) / 2 $$

So there are $1000-2$ restrictions on $x_2$.

For $x_3$ to not be in between any two numbers that average to $x_3$ we must have

$$x_3 \neq (x_1 + x_4) / 2  \\
... \\
x_3 \neq (x_1 + x_{1000}) / 2 $$
and

$$ x_3 \neq (x_2 + x_4) / 2  \\
... \\
x_3 \neq (x_2 + x_{1000}) / 2 $$

So there are $2\times(1000-3)$ restrictions on $x_3$.

In general there are $(1000-n)(n-1)$ restrictions on $x_n$. In total there are

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{999}{(1000-n)(n-1)} = 166,167,000$$

restrictions that must be satisfied.

A given restriction (e.g. $x_2 \neq (x_1 + x_3) / 2$) can only bind if $x_1$ and $x_3$ have the same parity (both odd or both even), otherwise $ (x_1 + x_3) / 2$ will not be an integer, so it will be irrelevant. There are $500\times499$ ways to choose two even numbers and $500\times499$ ways to choose two odd numbers from $1, ..., 1000$. So there is $2\times500\times499$ ways that each restriction can be broken. Therefore there is at most

$$ 2\times500\times499\times166,167,000 = 207,293,332,500,000 $$

arrangements of $1, ..., 1000$ that have at least one restriction being broken. The total number of arrangements of $1, ..., 1000$ is much larger at $1000!$, which is a 2568 digit number. Since there are fewer arrangements that breach one or more restriction than there are possible arrangements, there must be ways to arrange the integers such that no restrictions are breached.

So what have I missed here, or is it legitimate.

Comment: I don't see why you need to enforce same parity on $x_1,x_3$ in your example, since in the original phrasing of the problem it doesn't seem to imply that as something to be considered. 


It also doesn't really make any sense, since in any arrangement you can always pick 2 numbers of different parity and check between them.

Comment: @shou if the numbers have different parity, their average will not be an integer. Since we're only arranging the integers, we don't need to worry about restrictions that outlaw numbers that aren't integers.

Comment: There are LOTS of ways that the restriction can be broken. EG $x_2 = (x_1 + x_3) / 2$ is satisfied by "$1, 3, 5, \text{anything else}$", so there are at least $997!$ broken ways. This is much larger than your 15 digit number claiming to be an upper bound for "at least one restriction being broken".

Comment: I don't see a quick way to fix your solution. Since $2 \times 500 \times 499 \times 166167000 \times 997! >> 1000!$, we'd need to involve PIE to hunt down an upper bound that is $ < 1000!$. Unfortunately, this can be quite the mess.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin, but why do you say there are $997!$ ways that $x_2 = (x_1 + x_3) / 2$ can be satisfied? I think there's $ \sum_{n=1}^{999}{n(999-n)} $ ways to choose $x_1$ and $x_3$ such that $0<x_2<1000$. And half of those solutions for $x_2$ will not be integers. So still more than what I initially thought, but less than $997!$, unless there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: I am only using $x_ 1 = 1, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 5$. Thereafter, there are 997 options for $x_4$, 996 options for $x_5$, 995 options for $x_6$, so on and so forth.

Comment: @CalvinLin your comments seem to comprise an answer